# Compilation of JNI program on linux- Fedora core?

Tags: java, c, linux, java-native-interface

I was trying to explore the JNI part in Linux. I am from the C background. I was trying to use JNI so that I can make the UI in Java easily. I believe the UI can be made in Javascript/html. This can call the Java api's easily. Through Java Api's I can call the C/C++ API's .  I believe this is the easiest way to make a UI. Thus, I am trying out JNI. Here is the sample code, I made.

**Hello.java**

```
public class Hello { 
  public native void sayHi(String who, int times);
    static { System.loadLibrary("HelloImpl"); }
    public static void main (String[] args) { 
      Hello hello = new Hello(); 
      hello.sayHi(args[0], Integer.parseInt(args[1]));
    }
}
```

And later

```
javac Hello.java
javah -jni Hello
```

Now, I am writing hello.c program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "Hello.h"

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_Hello_sayHi
  (JNIEnv *, jobject, jstring, jint)
{
   printf("Shreyas.. HEllo world...\r\n");

}
```

I am facing a problem while compiling hello.c program.

```
$ gcc -c  hello.c -I/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_45/include/ -I/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_45/include/linux/
hello.c: In function ‘Java_Hello_sayHi’:
hello.c:5:3: error: parameter name omitted
hello.c:5:3: error: parameter name omitted
hello.c:5:3: error: parameter name omitted
hello.c:5:3: error: parameter name omitted
```

Can you please help me on this? Also, do you agree JNI is a good way to implement a complete stack solution- UI(JAVASCRIPT)+JAVA+C/C++->Linux?

Comment: Which part of "parameter name omitted" is ambigous? It is good traditon to give parameters in C a name. And no, this is not a good idea at all, as it requires thorough knowledge of all of {C, Java, Javascript}

Comment: Are you confusing Java with Javascript? They are not the same.

Comment: C and C++ are different languages. What you wrote is valid C++, but not valid C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add names for the parameters in the function definition in `hello.c`. For example:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_Hello_sayHi
  (JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jstring str, jint i)
{
   printf("Shreyas.. HEllo world...\r\n");
}
```